# IOS how to change annotation pin color in radius

Tags: ios

I am using mapview and i find current location in mapview. After that I draw a radius on specific area there are many pin points. I want to change pins colour that are in radius area.
How do I do it?

How do I do it?
My source code of radius is

```
 MKCircle *circle = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:_currentLocationCoordinate radius:10000];
    [_mapView addOverlay:circle];

- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay
{


    MKCircleView *circleView = [[MKCircleView alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay];
    [circleView setFillColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    [circleView setStrokeColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [circleView setAlpha:0.5f];
    return circleView;


}
```

I want to change pin color that are in give radius

Answer (score 0):

Annotations are dequeued from the same instances (like table view cells), so I think you have to define a different colored pin in `mapView:viewForAnnotation:` for all annotations within the radius.